# Div's not properly aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css

Here is the site in question:
http://jayduff.co.uk/

I previously had the images/links on the left and the header on the left, I decided to change it to make it more standardized but the top two divs that hold the title and the links don't seem to align up properly anymore?

Here is the CSS for both my link div and my title div (you can also view the source of my link above)

```
    #title { 
      float:left;
      font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
      font-color: #6D929B;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;  
    }

    #links { 
      margin-top:40px;
    }
```

I then have a div below... which holds my body text

```
   #mainText {
     width: 450px;
     word-wrap: break-word; 
     margin-left:45px;
   }
```

I'm pretty sure I am missing something from the div styles above and that is causing the top two divs to not be properly aligned with the third div below it?

Here is an example of how it should be

```
title                links
**************************** 
* JOSHUA DUFFY *  O O O O  *                                                         
****************************
* mainbody                 *
*                          *
*                          *
****************************
```

Hope that makes sense, where am I going wrong? I'm pretty sure its not the placement of my divs just the attributes above? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  #mainText {
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 45px;
        width: 450px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

#links {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#title {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular',sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jassi, thank you so much, so it was the clear: both on my bottom div causing the overlap? I also see you have added in float: left to the links also, does this float to the left of something already there then I assume?

By the way I have updated it and it works, I just need to mess with the padding for it to line up nice!

Comment: I've give you an 'accepted answer' I cant upvote due to low rep!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are missing `float:left;` on your links div style....

Comment: Hi, I've added it in thanks to Jassi below... Its strange because it worked the other way round with only the links having float: left included!

Comment: So my answer was right, give it a like! :-D You can read more about floats here http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ its very usefull to know how they works...

Comment: Great thanks, I cant like because my rep is too low :( But you've got some real life rep from me!